# Count rows by group in Dplyr: Evaluation error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to count the number of rows using dplyr after using group_by. I have the following data:

```
scenario    pertubation    population    
   A            1             20
   B            1             30
   C            1             40
   D            1             50
   A            2             15
   B            2             25
```

And I'm using the following code to group_by and mutate:

```
test <- all_scenarios %>%
        group_by(scenario) %>%
        mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(population)),
               exceedance_probability = rank / count(pertubation)) %>%
        select(scenario, pertubation, All.ages, rank, exceedance_probability)
```

But I keep encoutering this error message and I am unsure of what it means, or why I keep getting it?

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')".
```

I would like my output data to look something like this:

```
scenario    pertubation    population  rank    exceedance_probability  
   A            1             20        12           0.06  
   B            1             30        7            0.035
   C            1             40        2            0.01 
   D            1             50        1            0.005
   A            2             15        34           0.17
   B            2             25        28           0.14
```

To calculate the exceedance probability I just need to divide the rank by the number of observations, but I've found it hard to do this in dplyr after a group_by statement. Am I ordering the dplyr statements incorrectly?

Comment: `count` should be used on data.frame.  Your example and output seems to be different.  Perhaps use `all_scenarios %>% group_by(scenario) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(population)),  exceedance_probability = rank / table(pertubation))`

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `count` separately and join with the original dataset

```
all_scenarios %>% 
      count(pertubation) %>% 
      left_join(all_scenarios, ., by = 'pertubation') %>%
      group_by(scenario) %>%
      mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(population)),  exceedance_probability = rank /n)
```

---

Or instead of using `count`, we can do a second `group_by` and get the `n()`

```
all_scenarios %>%
   group_by(scenario) %>% 
   mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(population))) %>% 
   group_by(pertubation) %>% 
   mutate( exceedance_probability = rank /n())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the

```
count(pertubation)
```

part of the code. You cannot use count in a group_by scenario. I can't find a good explanation why, but it won't work. Just use

```
n()
```

in place of it in the code. Since youre grouping by scenario, and each scenario-pertubation is unique in your dataset, by counting the number of rows in each scenario you are effectively counting the number of values or pertubation for each scenario.